# Text transformed in an <input> field does not trigger its onChange

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, onchange

Code here:

```
import React from "react";
import "./style.css";
import {useRef, useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import * as wanakana from 'wanakana';
export default function App() {
  const [text, setText] = useState('same text')
  const [kana, setKana] = useState('')
  const inputRef = useRef(null)
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(inputRef)
    wanakana.bind(inputRef.current)
  },[])
  return (
    <div>
      <h1> kana conversion app</h1>
      <p>text: {text}</p>
      <p> conversion: {kana} </p>
      <input ref={inputRef} value={text} onChange={(e) => setText(e.target.value)} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Sandbox here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-mz6mch?file=src%2FApp.js

I'm using [wanakana bind()](https://wanakana.com/docs/bind.js.html) to transform romaji text entered into an `<input>` field into hiragana.  The transformation works in the input, e.g. if I type "shi" into the field it converts into "し". However, the state variable `text` I'm using to store the input value isn't updated and still only has "sh" in it. It's only after I type another consonant that the し makes it into the state variable. Anytime `wanakana.bind` is triggered and transforms the contents of the input field, the input's onChange isn't triggered.  How can I keep the state variable up to date with the contents of the input after a transformation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `onInput` event instead of `onChange`. The `onInput` is called when the text is changed by `.bind()`, and the state is updated as well ([blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-7iv2ub?file=src%2FApp.js)):

```
import { useRef, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import * as wanakana from 'wanakana';
export default function App() {
  const [text, setText] = useState('same text');
  const inputRef = useRef(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(inputRef);
    wanakana.bind(inputRef.current);
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1> kana conversion app</h1>
      <p>text: {text}</p>
      <input
        ref={inputRef}
        value={text}
        onInput={(e) => setText(e.target.value)}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Old answer**:

Don't use the `.bind()` method. Instead use the `toHiragana()` function to convert the text when you set the state, and the state would would update the input with the converted characters ([blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-nfad6j?file=src%2FApp.js)):

```
import {useState} from 'react';
import { toHiragana } from 'wanakana';
export default function App() {
  const [text, setText] = useState('same text')

  const changeHandler = e => {
    setText(toHiragana(e.target.value))
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1> kana conversion app</h1>
      <p>text: {text}</p>
      <input value={text} onChange={changeHandler} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: That's what I was using before, but that method brings up a lot of edge cases that I switched to `bind` to avoid, e.g. typing 'nn' results in 'んん' rather than one 'ん', and 'nyu' gives 'んゆ' not 'にゅ'.

Comment: @Max - See updated answer.

Comment: That worked!  Thank you much.

Comment: You're welcome :)